# How do I 'share' more than 8 tracks on a playlist?

Tags: soundcloud, playlist

I have posted the entire playlist but only 8 tracks of 11 and 8 of 12 (of complete cds) are displaying on the website page I've posted to.

My webpage under development is posted at http://marionwalsh.konductor.net/music.html

I have requested help from SoundCloud but have not heard back yet.

Answer (score 0):

All the tracks are there, it's just that you have to scroll inside the players to see them. I guess you could also make the widgets a bit higher so they show all the tracks in the playlists.